# How can get value of variable from more than one class with string

Tags: c#, reflection

i am trying to make table which table can load various data. the data format is class and in class has various variable which format are string, float, and double.

My data format is below. All of data will save into TotalData class

```
public class TotalData
{
    public List<A> aList;
    public List<B> bList;
}

public class A
{
    public int classA_intA;
    public int classA_intB;
    public float classA_floatA;
    public float classA_floatB;
}

public class B
{
    public int classB_intA;
    public int classB_intB;
    public double classB_doubleA;
    public double classB_doubleB;
    public double classB_doubleC;
    public double classB_doubleD;
    public double classB_doubleE;
    public double classB_doubleF;
}
```

After this set up, I want to search specific data by name of class and name of variable.

For example if I want to get **classB_doubleB**, then i need name of **bList** as string to search from TotalData and name of classB_doubleB so I can get value of **classB_doubleB**

```
public object GetValueFromTotalData(string getDataFromClass, 
                                    string nameOfVariable, 
                                    TotalData data, 
                                    int indexOfList) 
{
    //The string getDataFromClass selects a list to find the variable.

    //The string nameOfVariable selects variable which in selected class

    //indexofList is for choose index of aList or bList
    return value;
}
```

I hope someone can figure out my problem. thank you. :)

PS. The Script below is my Data format for real work.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TotalData
{
    public string date;
    public string symbol;
    public string fillingDate;
    public string acceptedDate;
    public string period;
    public string link;
    public string finalLink;
    public List<IncomeStatement> IncomeStatement;
    public List<BalanceSheet> BalanceSheet;
    public List<CashFlow> CashFlow;
    public List<FinancialRatios> FinancialRatios;
    public List<EnterpriceValue> EnterpriceValue;
    public List<KeyMetrics> KeyMetrics;
    public List<FinancialGrowth> FinancialGrowth;


       public TotalData(IncomeStatements incomeStatement, List<BalanceSheet> balance, List<CashFlow> cashFlow, List<FinancialRatios> financialRatios, List<EnterpriceValue> enterpriceValue, List<KeyMetrics> keyMetrics, List<FinancialGrowth> financialGrowth)
    {
        this.date = incomeStatement.date;
        this.symbol = incomeStatement.symbol;
        this.fillingDate = incomeStatement.fillingDate;
        this.acceptedDate = incomeStatement.acceptedDate;
        this.period = incomeStatement.period;
        this.link = incomeStatement.link;
        this.finalLink = incomeStatement.finalLink;
        this.IncomeStatement = incomeStatement;
        this.BalanceSheet = balance;
        this.CashFlow = cashFlow;
        this.FinancialRatios = financialRatios;
        this.EnterpriceValue = enterpriceValue;
        this.KeyMetrics = keyMetrics;
        this.FinancialGrowth = financialGrowth;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class IncomeStatements : IncomeStatement
{
    public string date;
    public string symbol;
    public string fillingDate;
    public string acceptedDate;
    public string period;
    public string link;
    public string finalLink;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class IncomeStatement
{
    public double revenue;
    public double costOfRevenue;
    public double grossProfit;
    public double grossProfitRatio;


    [Header("Cost And Expenses")]
    public double researchAndDevelopmentExpenses;
    public double generalAndAdministrativeExpenses;
    public double sellingAndMarketingExpenses;
    public double otherExpenses;
    public double operatingExpenses;
    public double costAndExpenses;
    public double interestExpense;


    [Header("EBITDA")]
    public double depreciationAndAmortization;
    public double ebitda;
    public double ebitdaratio;


    [Header("Income")]
    public double operatingIncome;
    public double operatingIncomeRatio;
    public double totalOtherIncomeExpensesNet;
    public double incomeBeforeTax;
    public double incomeBeforeTaxRatio;
    public double incomeTaxExpense;
    public double netIncome;
    public double netIncomeRatio;


    [Header("EPS")]
    public double eps;
    public double epsdiluted;
    public double weightedAverageShsOut;
    public double weightedAverageShsOutDil;
}


[System.Serializable]
public class BalanceSheet
{

    [Header("Current Assets")]
    public double cashAndCashEquivalents;
    public double shortTermInvestments;
    public double cashAndShortTermInvestments;
    public double netReceivables;
    public double inventory;
    public double otherCurrentAssets;
    public double totalCurrentAssets;

    [Header("Non Current Assets")]
    public double propertyPlantEquipmentNet;
    public double goodwill;
    public double intangibleAssets;
    public double goodwillAndIntangibleAssets;
    public double longTermInvestments;
    public double taxAssets;
    public double otherNonCurrentAssets;
    public double totalNonCurrentAssets;

    [Header("Total Assets")]
    public double otherAssets;
    public double totalAssets;


    [Header("CURRENT LIABILITIES")]
    public double accountPayables;
    public double shortTermDebt;
    public double taxPayables;
    public double deferredRevenue;
    public double otherCurrentLiabilities;
    public double totalCurrentLiabilities;


    [Header("NON CURRENT LIABILITIES")]
    public double longTermDebt;
    public double deferredRevenueNonCurrent;
    public double deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent;
    public double otherNonCurrentLiabilities;
    public double totalNonCurrentLiabilities;


    [Header("TOTAL LIABILITIES")]
    public double otherLiabilities;
    public double totalLiabilities;


    [Header("STOCKHOLDERS EQUITY")]
    public double commonStock;
    public double retainedEarnings;
    public double accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss;
    public double othertotalStockholdersEquity;
    public double totalStockholdersEquity;


    [Header("LIABILITIES and EQUITY")]
    public double totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity;


    [Header("INVESTMENT and DEBT")]
    public double totalInvestments;
    public double totalDebt;
    public double netDebt;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class CashFlow
{

    [Header("CashProvidedByOperatingActivites")]
    public double netIncome;
    public double depreciationAndAmortization;
    public double deferredIncomeTax;
    public double stockBasedCompensation;
    public double changeInWorkingCapital;
    public double accountsReceivables;
    public double inventory;
    public double accountsPayables;
    public double otherWorkingCapital;
    public double otherNonCashItems;
    public double netCashProvidedByOperatingActivities;


    [Header("CashProvidedByInvestingActivites")]
    public double investmentsInPropertyPlantAndEquipment;
    public double acquisitionsNet;
    public double purchasesOfInvestments;
    public double salesMaturitiesOfInvestments;
    public double otherInvestingActivites;
    public double netCashUsedForInvestingActivites;


    [Header("CashProvidedByFinancingingActivites")]
    public double debtRepayment;
    public double commonStockIssued;
    public double commonStockRepurchased;
    public double dividendsPaid;
    public double otherFinancingActivites;
    public double netCashUsedProvidedByFinancingActivities;


    [Header("Other")]
    public double effectOfForexChangesOnCash;


    [Header("Cash&CashFlow")]
    public double netChangeInCash;
    public double cashAtEndOfPeriod;
    public double cashAtBeginningOfPeriod;
    public double operatingCashFlow;
    public double capitalExpenditure;
    public double freeCashFlow;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class FinancialRatios
{

    public float currentRatio;
    public float quickRatio;
    public float cashRatio;
    public float daysOfSalesOutstanding;
    public float daysOfInventoryOutstanding;
    public float operatingCycle;
    public float daysOfPayablesOutstanding;
    public float cashConversionCycle;
    public float grossProfitMargin;
    public float operatingProfitMargin;
    public float pretaxProfitMargin;
    public float netProfitMargin;
    public float effectiveTaxRate;
    public float returnOnAssets;
    public float returnOnEquity;
    public float returnOnCapitalEmployed;
    public float netIncomePerEBT;
    public float ebtPerEbit;
    public float ebitPerRevenue;
    public float debtRatio;
    public float debtEquityRatio;
    public float longTermDebtToCapitalization;
    public float totalDebtToCapitalization;
    public float interestCoverage;
    public float cashFlowToDebtRatio;
    public float companyEquityMultiplier;
    public float receivablesTurnover;
    public float payablesTurnover;
    public float inventoryTurnover;
    public float fixedAssetTurnover;
    public float assetTurnover;
    public float operatingCashFlowPerShare;
    public float freeCashFlowPerShare;
    public float cashPerShare;
    public float payoutRatio;
    public float operatingCashFlowSalesRatio;
    public float freeCashFlowOperatingCashFlowRatio;
    public float cashFlowCoverageRatios;
    public float shortTermCoverageRatios;
    public float capitalExpenditureCoverageRatio;
    public float dividendPaidAndCapexCoverageRatio;
    public float dividendPayoutRatio;
    public float priceBookValueRatio;
    public float priceToBookRatio;
    public float priceToSalesRatio;
    public float priceEarningsRatio;
    public float priceToFreeCashFlowsRatio;
    public float priceToOperatingCashFlowsRatio;
    public float priceCashFlowRatio;
    public float priceEarningsToGrowthRatio;
    public float priceSalesRatio;
    public float dividendYield;
    public float enterpriseValueMultiple;
    public float priceFairValue;

}
[System.Serializable]
public class EnterpriceValue
{
    public float stockPrice;
    public long numberOfShares;
    public long marketCapitalization;
    public long minusCashAndCashEquivalents;
    public long addTotalDebt;
    public long enterpriseValue;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class KeyMetrics
{

    public float revenuePerShare;
    public float netIncomePerShare;
    public float operatingCashFlowPerShare;
    public float freeCashFlowPerShare;
    public float cashPerShare;
    public float bookValuePerShare;
    public float tangibleBookValuePerShare;
    public float shareholdersEquityPerShare;
    public float interestDebtPerShare;
    public float marketCap;
    public float enterpriseValue;
    public float peRatio;
    public float priceToSalesRatio;
    public float pocfratio;
    public float pfcfRatio;
    public float pbRatio;
    public float ptbRatio;
    public float evToSales;
    public float enterpriseValueOverEBITDA;
    public float evToOperatingCashFlow;
    public float evToFreeCashFlow;
    public float earningsYield;
    public float freeCashFlowYield;
    public float debtToEquity;
    public float debtToAssets;
    public float netDebtToEBITDA;
    public float currentRatio;
    public float interestCoverage;
    public float incomeQuality;
    public float dividendYield;
    public float payoutRatio;
    public float salesGeneralAndAdministrativeToRevenue;
    public float researchAndDdevelopementToRevenue;
    public float intangiblesToTotalAssets;
    public float capexToOperatingCashFlow;
    public float capexToRevenue;
    public float capexToDepreciation;
    public float stockBasedCompensationToRevenue;
    public float grahamNumber;
    public float roic;
    public float returnOnTangibleAssets;
    public float grahamNetNet;
    public float workingCapital;
    public float tangibleAssetValue;
    public float netCurrentAssetValue;
    public float investedCapital;
    public float averageReceivables;
    public float averagePayables;
    public float averageInventory;
    public float daysSalesOutstanding;
    public float daysPayablesOutstanding;
    public float daysOfInventoryOnHand;
    public float receivablesTurnover;
    public float payablesTurnover;
    public float inventoryTurnover;
    public float roe;
    public float capexPerShare;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class FinancialGrowth
{
    public float revenueGrowth;
    public float grossProfitGrowth;
    public float ebitgrowth;
    public float operatingIncomeGrowth;
    public float netIncomeGrowth;
    public float epsgrowth;
    public float epsdilutedGrowth;
    public float weightedAverageSharesGrowth;
    public float weightedAverageSharesDilutedGrowth;
    public float dividendsperShareGrowth;
    public float operatingCashFlowGrowth;
    public float freeCashFlowGrowth;
    public float tenYRevenueGrowthPerShare;
    public float fiveYRevenueGrowthPerShare;
    public float threeYRevenueGrowthPerShare;
    public float tenYOperatingCFGrowthPerShare;
    public float fiveYOperatingCFGrowthPerShare;
    public float threeYOperatingCFGrowthPerShare;
    public float tenYNetIncomeGrowthPerShare;
    public float fiveYNetIncomeGrowthPerShare;
    public float threeYNetIncomeGrowthPerShare;
    public float tenYShareholdersEquityGrowthPerShare;
    public float fiveYShareholdersEquityGrowthPerShare;
    public float threeYShareholdersEquityGrowthPerShare;
    public float tenYDividendperShareGrowthPerShare;
    public float fiveYDividendperShareGrowthPerShare;
    public float threeYDividendperShareGrowthPerShare;
    public float receivablesGrowth;
    public float inventoryGrowth;
    public float assetGrowth;
    public float bookValueperShareGrowth;
    public float debtGrowth;
    public float rdexpenseGrowth;
    public float sgaexpensesGrowth;
}
```

Comment: Both the classes are the same only differing by property name in a less than optimal way? Usually you would just use LINQ to search each list, though its really hard to know where you want to go from here, maybe you can add more details?

Comment: @TheGeneral Actually i have 6 classes and all of that has different data format. but all variables are float, int, double or long.

Comment: You could use reflection, but I advise against it (a lot). So you want to search both lists and properties for a value as text?

Comment: I would just put a switch/case mess since everything is fixed

Comment: You may need to name the different instances of class A or B in a dictionary so you can search each one by name.

Comment: @TheGeneral I want to get variable in list when i want to show up on table

Comment: @Rufw91 My data class come from json through JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. Therefore i dont want to use dictionary if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the best way to resolve your issue. Make use of if statement to control the flow of your application.

```
public object GetValueFromTotalData(string getDataFromClass, 
                                    string nameOfVariable, 
                                    TotalData data, 
                                    int indexOfList) 
{
    //check the value string getDataFromClass and initialize the correct class to search from
    if(getDataFromClass == "aList"){
        //initialize and access aList
    } else {
        //initialize and access bList
    }

    //use the same if statements as above to access the correct class and initialize it

    //again use an if statement to select index of item from the list set up above
    return value;
}
```

However, you can make use of an interface which you can be using to initialize the correct class. Both concrete classes would inherit from this interface and you will be initializing the interface using the correct class in your method.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remodel the class `TotalData` as follows:

```
public class TotalData
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<string,A>> aList;
    public List<KeyValuePair<string,B>> bList;
}
```

Then if you want to access a specific `A` or `B` object you can search the list:

```
var searchresult = totalData.aList.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Key=="aListname");
```

Alternatively, you can use  `Dictionary` (as in Dictionary<string,object>) in lieu of `List` as follows:

```
public class TotalData
    {
        public Dictionary<string,A> aList;
        public Dictionary<string,B> bList;
    }
```

To access a specific instance of `A` you would use:

```
var aListObject = totalData["aListname"];
```

Comment: Well my Data format class come from json. In my opinion, Using dictionary  is more hard to convert all my data.

Comment: Consider this, you have a 'TotalData' object with 'aList' = {aObject1,aObject2} and 'bList' = {bObject1, bObject2}.
To get 'bObject2.classB_doubleA' you would need to know the index of 'bObject2' (which is 1 hence you get bList[1]).
if you dont know the index the you need to be able to identify each instance by a unique name hence the need for a Dictionary or List<KeyValuePair<string,object>>

Comment: I want to call one of variable in class and this progress using by string.

For example, If i want to get aObject2 in aList  from list at 3,  i just need name of class, name of variable and index. so all i need to input parameters are 2 string, Totaldata, and index

Comment: var myRevenueJune = TotalData.IncomeStatements[5].revenue;//0 lol

EDIT: Sorry i had misunderstood your question. You definitely want to use reflection.

Comment: Use this as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9274326/7740926

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not allowed to modify the classes to make them more late-binding friendly, you can do it with extension methods. I would break it down into parts to make it more readable.

```
public static class TotalDataReader
{
    static public IEnumerable<object> GetList(this TotalData source, string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "aList": return source.aList;
            case "bList": return source.bList;
            default: throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }

    static public object GetItem(this IEnumerable<object> list, int index)
    {
        return list.Skip(index).First();
    }

    static public object GetFieldValue(this object source, string fieldName)
    {
        return source.GetType().GetField(fieldName).GetValue(source);
    }
}
```

Once you have the parts working you can put it together pretty easily:

```
    public object GetValueFromTotalData(string getDataFromClass, string nameOfVariable, int indexOfList, TotalData data) 
    {
        return data
           .GetList(getDataFromClass)
           .GetItem(indexOfList);
           .GetFieldValue(nameOfVariable);
    }
```